# (top) vertical alignment of tabular

Tags: tables, xetex, vertical-alignment

I am a total beginner, I manage to make small changes in a template, but I don't quite understand LaTeX syntax yet. 
I have this code:

```
\newenvironment{cvskills}{
  \begin{center}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{1ex}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} r L{15.2cm}}
}{
    \end{tabular*}
  \end{center}
}
```

I would like to have the two entries of the table vertically aligned on top.
Could you please help me with that?

I apologize in advance for my inability to extrapolate from previously answered questions.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Please provide a small **yet complete** working code that demonstrates the problem.  A mere code snippet makes it difficult to infer what else may be going on.

Comment: What is the `L`(capital L) column type?

Comment: The code is part of a relatively complex code (CV awesome template). Unfortunately I don´t think I know what constitutes a complete working code for these lines. I thought that vertical alignment was a standard operation on tabulars. I don´t know what the L stands for, you suggest that is a costum made column type? in this case I could just trace back its definition and change the parameters there.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for your comments, that led me to find the answer to my problem. From Bernard answer

> What is the L(capital L) column type?

I understood that L was somehow a custom column type, so I looked in the code where the column L was defined:

```
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
```

As correctly argued by Steven B. The problem was outside the code I provided in my question. Nevertheless, once I understood where to look I just had to change the last 'm' in `m{#1}`, which defines the vertical alignment to the (M)iddle, to `p{#1}`, which (i guess) uses the default vertical alignment of the (P)aragraph.

Problem solved, and your help was essential for me to understand the solution. Thank you